# Problems retrieving Links from a document using JSOUP

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsoup

I'm doing a school project and I need to retrieve all links from a given url.

I should get a list of all "a[links]" and write that down into a document. Right now I'm stuck getting the links.

```
    public Set<String> getLinks(String url){
    Set<String> links = new HashSet<String>();

    try {


        Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(this.USER_AGENT).execute();

        Document doc = res.parse();

        Elements elements = doc.select("a");


        for(Element element: elements){
            links.add(element.attr("href"));

        }

        // }
        return links;



    } catch(IOException io){
        logger.error(io);
        System.err.println(io.getMessage());
        io.printStackTrace();
        return links;
    }
}
```

This is the user agent string I'm using

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) "
        + "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36";
```

Am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE:

I try running like this as a test on Main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Set<String> links = new HashSet<String>();

    try {

        // 1. Obtiene los links de un URL específico y regresa el
        // set de strings
        // escribe aquí tu código {

        Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(" https://gist.github.com/mark-cooper/1491327").userAgent("Mozilla").execute();

        Document doc = res.parse();

        Elements elements = doc.select("a[href]");


        for(Element element: elements){
            links.add(element.toString());

        }

        links.forEach(k -> System.out.println(k));

        // }



    } catch(IOException io){
        logger.error(io);
        System.err.println(io.getMessage());
        io.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

And I goot this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL:  https://gist.github.com/mark-cooper/1491327
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:78)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:38)
at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
at web.MainCrawler.main(MainCrawler.java:33)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:     %20https://gist.github.com/mark-cooper/1491327
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:76)
... 3 more
```

Comment: where exactly are you stuck ?

Comment: Is not getting any link. The set of strings "links" is empy.

Comment: remove the space from the url start

Comment: That did the trick. Now when I add the links to the set of strings in the first method. Is still empty, the return links. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: check the size of `elements`

Comment: why have you changed from `links.add(element.attr("href"));` to `links.add(element.toString());`